# How to add a value from one table to a particular row in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to use a command like this:

```
insert into PERSON (hometown)
where person_name="Peter"

select city from COUNTRY
where country_id= 2;
```

It is obviously wrong!

In a nutshell, **a command which will select a particular value** (country's city from the record where the id is 2) **from one table and add it to another table** (person's hometown whose name is Peter), **so basically a particular attribute's value from one table to another table's particular row.**

*What will be the command for that?*

Comment: Is this mysql or some other flavor, The update from syntax differs drastically between flavors.

Comment: @Ian Laird It is MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
UPDATE Person SET City=(SELECT City FROM Country WHERE Country_id = 2) 
WHERE Person_Name = 'Peter'
```

Comment: OK, this works for one value, but not more than that. I am editing my question.

Comment: I'm not sure what else you want it to do. Have you considered using foreign keys to match the tables, or joins in your select statements instead of copying the data from one table to another?

Comment: City is a foreign key in Person, from the Country table. So what I want is this: From the Country table, select the city from the row where the country id is 2, and insert it into the city column in the person table in the row where the name of the person is Peter.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming mysql: you want to do something like this.

```
UPDATE Person, Country
SET Person.City=Country.City
WHERE Person.Person_Name = 'Peter'
AND City.Country_id = 2
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

If you are doing insert specificly, i would recomend something like this:

```
insert into PERSON (hometown, person_name)
select city, 'Peter' from COUNTRY where country_id= 2;
```

Just make sure the ID is unique or you will end up with more then one record named 'peter'.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is 'Criteria' in the code you provided?